# How to style material-ui textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to work out how to style a [material-ui TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) component.

```
<TextField
    id="email"
    label="Email"
    className={classes.textField}
    value={this.state.form_email}
    onChange={this.handle_change('form_email')}
    margin="normal"
/>
```

My classes are created as follows:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    textField: {
        width: '90%',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        color: 'white',
        paddingBottom: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
        fontWeight: 500
    },
});
```

My problem is that I can not seem to get the colour of the text field to change to white.  I seem to be able to apply styling to the overall text field (because the width styling works etc)... but I think the problem is that I am not applying the styles further down the chain and into the actual input.

I have tried to look at the other answers dealing with passing inputProps but have had no success.

Have tried everything to the best of my ability but think I need to ask if anyone knows what I am doing wrong.

> What it currently looks like

[image: textfield with a blue background and a slightly lighter blue label]

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need to add the `InputProps` property to the TextField.

```
const styles = theme => ({
    textField: {
        width: '90%',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',            
        paddingBottom: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
        fontWeight: 500
    },
    input: {
        color: 'white'
    }
});
```

JSX:

```
<TextField
    id="email"
    label="Email"
    className={styles.textField}
    value={this.state.form_email}
    onChange={this.handle_change('form_email')}
    margin="normal"
    InputProps={{
        className: styles.input,
    }}
/>
```

As an aside, you can also style the label or use an override as described [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11244).

Comment: How are the two `className`s different, in other words, why doe MUI need more than one? (vs. for example the `white` color going into the `textField` CSS rule from the theme?

Comment: Thanks this worked well. The Material-UI docs aren't clear when it comes to letting you know that you have to use `InputProps` to style text fields.

Comment: thanks my friend worked just fine

Comment: Where do I get `classes` from?

Comment: @AleksaRistic I've updated the code - it should have been `styles` not `classes`.

Answer (score 95):

All the answers here shows how to style things with InputProps or inputProps, but no one explained why, and how it works. And no one explained whats the difference between inputProps and InputProps

```
<TextField    
    variant="outlined"
    // inputProps are used to pass attributes native to the underlying 
    // HTML input element, e.g. name, id, style.
    inputProps={{
      style: { textAlign: 'center' },
    }

    // InputProps (capital I) passes props to the wrapper Material 
    // component. Can be  one of the following: Input, FilledInput, 
    // OutlinedInput. You can pass here anything that the underlying
    // Material component uses: error, value, onChange, and classes.
    InputProps={{
       // Usually you don't need className, the `classes` object will
       // be sufficient. However, you can also use it and this will
       // add your class to the div of the InputBase.
       className: styles.slider_filter_input, 
       classes: {
          root: classes.root
          focused: classes.focused
          // The list of keys you pass here depend on your variant
          // If for example you used variant="outlined", then you need
          // to check the CSS API of the OutlinedInput.
       }
    }}
/>
```

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-drawer-8p6wv) showing the ideas above.

Comment: thanks finally someone explained. It would be nice if you could explain why style props is working sometimes ( example: <TextField style={{margin: 15, color: 'blue'}} />, margin works but not color... thanks again

Comment: @NielsDominguez What you are describing is not related to Material-Ui but to how css works, when you are adding a style to a component and that style is not working that means some more specific styles are applying to that rule - based on css specificity rules.

Comment: @NielsDominguez Anyway notice that your example <TextField style={{margin: 15, color: 'blue'}} />, will not work anyway because you are passing style as a prop to TextField component, and that component is not doing anything with that prop.style props are applied to as inline style when they are  passed to native dom elements like div. When you pass them to a React Component that react Component  needs to handle it just like any other prop.Usually material ui Components pass styles  to underlying native elements  using props like inputProps.

Comment: Not that it ever matters to say this but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

This is a solution with inline styles:

```
<TextField
    style={{
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    }}
    InputProps={{
        style: {
            color: "red"
        }
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest keeping your style within a theme.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInputBase: {
      input: {
        background: "#fff",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This is the best solution if you are using many TextFields.

Comment: what does the html line look like?

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on what exactly are you trying to change.

The documentation has a bunch of examples on custom TextFields, take a look at them here:

https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#customized-inputs

More information about customization can be found here:

https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

and

https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/

Have you tried using !important for the color changes? I had the same problem when I tried to set a default color for the border of an outlined TextField

Take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color

Answer (score 4):

You cann pass styles to any of the children elements in the hierarchy:

`TextField > Input > input (HTML element)`

Notice the uper or lower case in `InputProps` vs. `inputProps`

```
// pass styles (or props) to the Input component 
<TextField InputProps={{className: classes.input}} />

// pass styles (or props) to the inner input element 
<TextField inputProps={{className: classes.input}} />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `inputStyle` prop on `TextField`. From the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)...

> inputStyle (object) - Override the inline-styles of the TextField's input
>   element. When multiLine is false: define the style of the input
>   element. When multiLine is true: define the style of the container of
>   the textarea.

```
<TextField inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

As of MUI V5, you can use the sx prop to change style settings. You still need to use inputProps to pass down those props to the input field. You could consider doing it like this:

```
              <TextField
                sx={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                inputProps={{ sx: {color: '#fff'} }}  
              />
```

[The SX prop in MUI V5](https://next.material-ui.com/system/the-sx-prop/)

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextField
          color="whitish"
          label="Enter Your Name"
          type="Text"
          InputLabelProps={{
            style: { color: "white" },
          }}
          sx={{
            ".css-x2l1vy-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
              color: "white",
            },
          }}
          InputProps={{
            sx: {
              ".css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                border: "2px solid white",
              },
              "&:hover": {
                ".css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                  border: "2px solid white",
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          size="medium"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setName(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
```

### Customize on_hover,color,border TextField

Comment: you wouldn't specifically target those generated classnames

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`FilledInput`](https://material-ui.com/api/filled-input/) component instead of `TextField`. Then you can use simple inline styling like this:

`style={{color: 'white' }}`

This also will lighten the placeholder text... hooray.

Answer (score 0):

Give a classname to the textfield.

```
            <TextField
            className={styles.search_bar}
            autoComplete={"off"}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <Box className={'search_icon_container'} component={"span"}>
                <IconButton>
                  <CiSearch fontSize={icon_default_size} />
                </IconButton>
                </Box>
              ),
            }}
            size={"small"}
            placeholder="Search"
          />
```

Do this in your CSS file.

```
.search_bar div{
   border-radius: 25px;
   width: 45vw;
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

It worked for me. :)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQWFa.png)