# remove padding of the textbox which comes from material ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to remove the padding from a textbox but the problem is it's coming from the Material UI.

I gave padding 0 for all the classes but padding is still not getting removed.

Can you tell me how to remove this padding?

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-input-1708 {
    padding: 18.5px 14px;
}
```

Here is my code and a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/m58841kkwp

```
cssLabel: {
    "&$cssFocused": {
      color: { borderColor: "red", padding: 0 }
    }
  },
  cssFocused: { borderColor: "red", padding: 0 },
  cssUnderline: {
    "&:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "red",
      padding: 0
    }
  },
  // cssOutlinedInput: {
  //   "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
  //     borderColor: "green"
  //   }
  // },

  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "& $notchedOutline": {
      //add this nested selector
      borderColor: "red",
      padding: 0
    },

    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green",
      padding: 0
    }
  },

  notchedOutline: { borderColor: "red", padding: 0 },
```

Comment: Have your tried `padding: 0!important` ?

Comment: @PabloDbSys : I updated but still not working https://codesandbox.io/s/m58841kkwp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one way to solve it could be to create a useful class and overwrite the styles of the material text field. This way you will make it reusable

I leave the example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-textfield-without-padding

**Note:** I left it with a 5px padding to make it look better as an example. You can customize it so you do not have padding

**Useful resources**

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html
- https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: thanks it worked...can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265169/css-position-absolute-making-the-textbox-go-down

Comment: can you tell me why you used this one in classname without this also its working fine ----> ${classes.textField}

Comment: classes.textField this is becauseI take it from this example https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/. 

About the syntax {`${classes.textField} without-padding`} is a javascript feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 52):

If you read the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) you can find inputProps (not InputProps) property that applies attributes to the native input element. As shown below you can pass a style attribute.

```
<TextField
    inputProps={{
       style: {
         padding: 5
       }
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This should be the official answer. Thanks @sudazzle

Comment: Thanks man, this is the perfect and easiest solution for me.

Comment: Or Like:       InputProps={{
        inputProps: { min: 1, style: { padding: 0 }}
      }}

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is reading this in 2022 (using `@mui/material`), the top answer didn't work for me for `varient="outline"` because removing the input padding didn't cause the label to be offset correctly.

I ended up getting the padding removed (and the label properly sized) by adding the `size="small"` prop to the TextField. So:

```
<TextField
   size="small"
/>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't support changing the actual padding size, but looking at the source for how it works would probably reveal how to do that.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer does not address initial position of floating labels.

Answer (score 4):

Solution is in this answer [How to style MaterialUI textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966413/how-to-style-material-ui-textfield)

passing className to TextField as well as InputProps

```
<TextField multiline={true} variant="outlined" rowsMax={10} placeholder="Notes" className={classes.formInput}
            InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.formAreaInput } }} fullWidth onChange={this.handleNotesInput} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer in this site: https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

```
const styles = theme => ({
  noPadding: {
    padding: 0
  },
});

// some code

const { classes } = this.props;

// some code

<OutlinedInput
  labelWidth={0}
  name="timeUnit"
  id="outlined-time-unit"
  classes={{input: classes.noPadding}}
/>
```

Comment: in your code.. use
inputProps={{
          style: { padding: 0 }
        }}
,.......not InputPros