# How to style material ui elements?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a TextField like so:

```
<TextField
    style={styles}
    className = "my-3"
    fullWidth
    id="filterBox"
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: <SearchIcon style={{color: "white"}} />,
        className: styles.input
    }}
    variant = "outlined"
    label = {this.state.label}
    onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}
/>
```

I am trying to style it via:

```
const styles = {
    textfield: {
      borderRadius: 2,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'white',
      height: 48,
      width: '150dp',
    },
    input:{
        color: 'white',
        borderColor: '#50fbdb',
        border: 1
    },
    formLabelRoot:{
        '&$formLabelFocused': { 
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
  };
```

However, it doesn't look anything like that. [image]

The docs don't specify a lot so I've been searching and found: [How to style material-ui textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966413/how-to-style-material-ui-textfield) but this is pretty much what I did and still I can't get the text to change (let alone the focused style).

Comment: what style you want in the  text-box?

Comment: I want the border to be 50fbdb and the search to be bold and white.

Comment: well  you Override the styles using: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-global-class-names    , also check if props can help you : https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: that's exactly what I've been reading. No idea why it won't work

Comment: for better understanding watch this video : https://youtu.be/YS9Q4O5hVzI

Comment: oh this is super useful! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is many solution.
If you want globally change the style of this component use [`createMuiTheme`](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#api)

If you want to make this change for a specific component you can use `withStyles` function.

An example below or in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-brattain-hcm24?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
const CssTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input' : {
      color: "white",
    },
    '& .MuiInputLabel-outlined':{color: "white"},
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: '#50fbdb',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'darkRed',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
})(TextField);

function App() {

  return (
    <CssTextField
        fullWidth
        id="filterBox"
        InputProps={{
            endAdornment: <SearchIcon style={{color: "white"}} />,
        }}
        variant = "outlined"
        label = "text field"
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some common confusion between the React way of styling by passing an *object*, and the Material-UI way of using the [MUI styles solution](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) to generate class-name *strings*.

Try the following stripped-down test component:

```
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useTestStyles = makeStyles({
  test1: {fontSize: 40},
  test2: {color: 'red'}
});

function TestComponent() {
  const testStyles = useTestStyles();
  console.log(testStyles);
  return null;
}
```

The console should log something like: `{test1: "makeStyles-test1-3", test2: "makeStyles-test2-4"}`

Note that the object properties are strings - internally-generated class-names. You can use these anywhere you would normally use a `className` property.

Example: `return <div className={testStyles.test2}>Red Text</div>;`

Or if you want to apply all class-names, any string concatination will work:

```
const classNames = [testStyles.test1, testStyles.test2].join(' ');
return <div className={classNames}>Big Red Text</div>;
```

In your InputProps above, you are trying to pass an object (styles.input) into the `className` property. That property expects a string class-name.

Also the styles object you pass into TextInput contains the attributes 'textfield', 'label' and 'formLabelRoot'. React applies these as if they are CSS styles, but the browser doesn't know what to do with this info, and so ignores it. Effectively, you are doing something like this:

`<div style={{textfield:'[Object]'}}>Unrecognized style</div>`

The docs and examples tend to use generic variable names like 'styles' which can be confusing, IMO.

#### TLDR;

Another difficulty seems to be due to a MUI component like TextField consisting of nested components (divs, labels, inputs etc) that we want to style directly. How do we pass down specific styles to the sub-components?

Material-UI gives you three ways to do this, although support differs across components.

1. defining the styles with [nested selectors](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors). This seems the most generic since it uses the `className` attribute. Material-UI helps by publishing the sub-class names for most sub-components.
2. using the [`classes` attribute](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop). This usually works, but some components don't support `classes`.
3. using specific properties such as `InputProps`. Simplest, but least generic, as the exact property is component-specific.

I had some confusion myself early on, so I hope this answer helps others.